# CRTP / Macros / Avoid casting pointer of derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance, c-preprocessor, crtp

Lately I've been working in some project and the thing is that we've encountered a situation in which we need to be able to do stuff like this.

```
#define TYPED(Type) \
    virtual Type *typedThis() const { return (Type*) this; }

class A {
public: 
TYPED(A)
virtual void describe() { std::cout << "I am type A\n"; }
static int x;
};

int A::x = 1;

class B : public A {
public: 
TYPED(B) 
virtual void describe() { std::cout << "I am type B\n"; }
static int x;
};

int B::x = 2;

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    B* b = new B();
    A* b2 = b;

    b->describe();
    b2->describe();

    std::cout << b->typedThis()->x << std::endl;
    std::cout << b2->typedThis()->x << std::endl; // AQUI DEBERIA DAR 2 !! :c
}
```

This is of course just a toy example. The basic idea of what we would like to do is to define a function typedThis() who does the casting of the pointer into the correct type and then access to the correct variable x, and printing out 2 instead of 1.

However, the output is the following:

```
I am type B
I am type B
2
1 //Here should also be 2
```

What I find really interesting is that the virtual method describe() seems to be working the way we want. Therefore, I could infer that the method typedThis() is also working the way we would like to. But if so, why does C++ see this pointer as an A* instead of an B*. If C++ saw this pointer like a B* then it would have used the correct variable x. **Can someone explain this to me?**

I tried using CRTP, however I don't feel like this would make things easier, because in the project we will be using a lot (A LOT) of different classes who derive between them constantly, I saw some articles of how to use CRTP when having multiple inheritance, however they are really messy and hard to integrate with what we have so far.

Comment: why should be 2 if it is not virtual? It will get resolved with the pointer base class instead of checking against any virtual table to resolve that function.

Comment: pba needs to be virtual.

Comment: Yes. Because this is just a toy example, I used a dummy method that just prints out a number. But in the actual code, we want to access some attributes that have the same name between the classes. Therefor, let's say that both A and B classes have an int static attribute x. Then we receive a pointer A* but with the pointer of an instance of B. Then if we want to get the value of x. What we get is the x value of the class A, and not the one of the class B. Which, in this example, would be equivalent of saying, we print out using the method pba() of A, instead of the method pba() of B.

Comment: The access to `x` only uses the type of the expression, not the actual value, since it is a property of the class rather than one of the object. Since `b->typedThis()` is a `B*`, you get `B::x`. However, `b2->typedThis()` is an `A*` so you get `A::x`. The fact that `b2` points to a `B` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all distractions from the example:

```
class A {
public: 
    virtual A *typedThis() const { return (A*) this; }
    static int x = 1;
};

class B : public A {
public: 
    virtual B *typedThis() const { return (B*) this; }
    static int x = 2;
};

int main()
{
    B* b1 = new B;
    A* b2 = b1;

    std::cout << b1->typedThis()->x << "\n";
    std::cout << b2->typedThis()->x << "\n";
}
```

`typedThis` doesn't do *anything*.

`b1->typedThis()` returns a `B*` which points to a `B`.

Likewise, `b1` itself is a `B*` which points to a `B`.

`b2->typedThis()` returns an `A*` which points to a `B`.

Likewise, `b2` itself is an `A*` which points to a `B`.

So `b1->typedThis()` is the same as `b1` and `b2->typedThis()` is the same as `b2`, and the last two lines of the example are equivalent to the following:

```
    std::cout << b1->x << "\n";
    std::cout << b2->x << "\n";
```

Also take note that your C-style casts discard the `const` qualifiers of the objects.

Comment: It didn't exactly solved my issues but was the most helpful answer, thanks!